# Delphi how to remove deleted properties from dfm in exe

Tags: delphi-10.2-tokyo, dfm

I have many dfms. I am using delete unwanted properties exe from this site [Delphi DFM properties remover](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/15667),  to remove deleted properties which are no longer required. Following code works fine except for some properties like if I want to delete property with name `Prop` then it deletes another property with name `SecondProp` along with `Prop`. mPropList contains each property on new line like
Prop1
Prop2
SecondProp
Propn

I doubt following code:

```
 if StrIPos(mPropList.Lines[K] + ' =', S) = 0 then
      begin
        LResult.Add(LSource[J]);
        continue;
      end;
```

How to skip `SecondProp` in such case?

I tried this

```pascal
if mPropList.Lines[K] = S then
      begin
        LResult.Add(LSource[J]);
        continue;
      end;
```

To match exact strings, but it didn't work.

This is delete button code

```pascal
procedure TfrmDeleteProp_MainForm.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
      LFile, LSource, LResult: TStringList;
      I, J, K, Processed, WasError, Removed: Integer;
      SkipPropData: Boolean;
      FLOpt: TFileListOptions;
      S: String;
begin
      LFile := TStringList.Create;
      LSource := TStringList.Create;
      LResult := TStringList.Create;
  try
    if chbxSubFolders.Checked then
      FLOpt := [flFullNames, flRecursive]
    else
      FLOpt := [flFullNames];

    if not AdvBuildFileList(IncludeTrailingBackslash(edPath.Text) + '*.DFM', faAnyFile, LFile, FLOpt) then
    begin
      MessageBox(Handle,
        'Invalid path specified. Can not process.',
        'Warning',
        MB_OK or MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
      exit;
    end;

    Processed := 0;
    WasError := 0;

    for I := 0 to LFile.Count - 1 do
    begin
      LSource.LoadFromFile(LFile[I]);
      Removed := 0;

      for K := 0 to mPropList.Lines.Count - 1 do
      begin
        if K > 0 then
          LSource.Assign(LResult);

        if Trim(mPropList.Lines[K]) = '' then
          continue;

        LResult.Clear;
        SkipPropData := False;

        for J := 0 to LSource.Count - 1 do
        begin
          S := Trim(LSource[J]);

          if SkipPropData then
          begin
            if (S > '') and (S[Length(S)] in [')', '}']) then
              SkipPropData := False;
            continue;
          end;

          if StrIPos(mPropList.Lines[K] + ' =', S) = 0 then
          begin
            LResult.Add(LSource[J]);
            continue;
          end;

          if (S > '') and (S[Length(S)] in ['(', '{']) then
            SkipPropData := True;

          Removed := Removed + 1;
        end;
      end;

      if Removed > 0 then
      begin
        if RenameFile(LFile[I], ChangeFileExt(LFile[I], '.BAK')) then
        begin
          LResult.SaveToFile(LFile[I]);
          Processed := Processed + 1;
        end else
        begin
          MessageBox(Handle,
            PChar('Can not create back up copy for file: ' + LFile[I] + #13#10'File is not processed.'),
            'Warning',
            MB_OK or MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
          WasError := WasError + 1;
        end;
      end;
    end;

    MessageBox(Handle,
      PChar(Format('Total files found: %d'#13#10'Properties were removed from: %d'#13#10'Error files: %d',
        [LFile.Count, Processed, WasError])),
      'Statistics',
      MB_OK or MB_ICONINFORMATION);
  finally
    LFile.Free;
    LSource.Free;
    LResult.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Check that the strings match exactly, not just that the property name contains the input...?

Comment: Show what you tried and explain how it didn't work, please.

Comment: @underscore_d I have added my trial code

Comment: Right, so your `mPropList.Lines` each contain something like `Prop = foo` or `SecondProp = bar`. Does the property name always start the line? And what is `LResult`? The lines that should be kept? Then you don't want to add to that if the strings match, but if they _don't_. Putting these together, you want to do `LResult.Add()`  only if `StrIPos(...) <> 1`, don't you? That way, you add lines that don't contain the property (`0`, i.e. `<1`) and those that contain it as a substring but not at the beginning (`>1`).

Comment: MPropList.Lines contains only property name and not value because values can be different, eg. Prop on first line , secondProp on second and so on.

Comment: so did you try comparing StrIPos() to <>1 ?

Comment: @underscore_d yes, it worked! Thank you

Comment: Great! You're welcome. I posted it as an answer with a slightly better explanation. Accepting/upvoting would be welcomed ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We established that:

- Your `mPropList.Lines` each contain something like `Prop =[...]` or `SecondProp =[...]`, and the property name always starts the line.
- `LResult` holds the lines that should be kept. So, you don't want to add to that if the strings match, but you *do* if they *don't*.

Putting these together, you want to do `LResult.Add()` only if `StrIPos(...) <> 1`. That way, you add

- lines that don't contain the property name (`StrIPos() == 0`, i.e. `< 1`) and
- lines that contain it as a substring but not at the start, i.e. only within *another* property name (`StrIPos > 1`).

The fixed code will thus look like:

```pascal
if StrIPos(mPropList.Lines[K] + ' =', S) <> 1 then
  begin
    LResult.Add(LSource[J]);
    continue;
  end;
```